# Raphaël JS draw angle lines dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, data-visualization, pi

I am drawing lines with [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com) manually, I would create infinite lines dynamically (with a foreach function).

```
var r = Raphael('canvas', 300, 300);

var axis = {
  2: "M 0 150 L 150 150",
  3: "M 150 0 L 150 150, M 150 150 L 280 225, M 150 150 L 20 225",
  4: "M 150 150 L 300 150, M 150 150 L 150 0, M 150 300 L 150 150, M 0 150 L 150 150",
  6: "M 150 0 L 150 150, M 150 150 L 280 225, M 150 150 L 20 225, M 280 75 L 150 150, M 20 75 L 150 150 ,M 150 150 L 150 300"
};

r.path(axis[6]).attr({'stroke-width':2, stroke:"#ff0000"}).toBack();
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkdJZ/)

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question? I see red lines on a black circle which, given the markup you've provided is what I would expect.

Comment: The coords are hard-coded, so I'm looking automate this process for growth the number of axis without write new coords :)

Comment: Create the string dynamically by appending the various fragments together would be one way.

Comment: @RobertLongson Have you seen a working example?

Comment: I need create infinite variations for data visualizations

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is division of the circle, the solution would require to :

1. Determine the angle in given number of divisions

   360/nrOfDivisons
2. Determine the coords of the ending points of all dividing lines using parametric equation for a circle:

   x = cx + r * cos(a)
   y = cy + r * sin(a)

the code would look as following:

```
var r = Raphael('canvas', 300, 300);    


var divideCircle = function(posX,posY,radius,nrOfDivisions){
    var xStart = posX
        , yStart = posY
        , step = 360 / nrOfDivisions
    ;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < nrOfDivisions ; i++){
        //x = cx + r * cos(a)
        //y = cy + r * sin(a)
        var xEnd = Math.cos(step * i *(Math.PI/ 180))*radius +  xStart,
            yEnd = Math.sin(step * i * (Math.PI/180))*radius +  yStart,
            pathString = 'M '+ xStart.toString() + ',' + yStart.toString() + 'L '+ xEnd.toString() + ',' + yEnd.toString()

        r.path(pathString).attr({'stroke-width':2, stroke:"#ff0000"}).toBack();        
    }
}

divideCircle(150,150,150,4);
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkdJZ/1/